# UITabBarController is lost when set a new ViewController

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I have the following TabBarController with the uiTabBarItems

> [Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4]

This struct works fine (Every ViewController is displayed correctly), my problem is:

When I change to another ViewController from Item1, Item2 ...  the TabBarItems bottom are hidden/lose

```
[, , , ]
```

I'm using the following code to change of viewController from Item1 ViewController

```
NewViewController *controller = [[NewViewController alloc]init];
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:controller, nil]];
```

is correct change of viewcontroller with the code showed previously?

EDIT.-

Basically I want to navigate on ViewControllers of Item1 (UITabBar) without lost the UITabBarItems

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the active tab, you should't use `setViewControllers:` since that replaces all your tabs. You should use `setSelectedIndex:` on your `UITabBarController` instead.

Comment: Yes, I can change of views correctly,  but my problem is: when I want to push a new viewcontroller on Item1 ... the uitabbaritem missing

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

call this method , where to present `UITabBar`

In .h,

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigation;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UITabBarController *tabbarcontroller;
```

In .m,

```
-(void)loadtabview
{

    self.tabbarcontroller = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *localControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];
    self.firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"firstViewController" bundle:nil];
    navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.firstViewController];
    self.viewController.navigationItem.title=@"First";
    [localControllersArray addObject:navigation];


    self.secondViewController = [[secondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:nil];
    navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];
    self.secondViewController.navigationItem.title=@"second";
    [localControllersArray addObject:navigation];


    self.ThirdViewController = [[Third ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Third ViewController" bundle:nil];
    navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ThirdViewController];
    self.secondViewController.navigationItem.title=@"Third";
    [localControllersArray addObject:navigation];

    tabbarcontroller.viewControllers = localControllersArray;
    self.tabbarcontroller.delegate = self;
    [self.tabbarcontroller setSelectedIndex:0];
    [self.window addSubview:tabbarcontroller.view];

}
```